# How do I fix Bower segmentation fault - Eclipse on Windows?

Tags: node.js, eclipse, bower, bower-install

I am having a consistent problem with bower in Windows - I am running Eclipse Neon and installed the current version of nodeclipse.

npm install works fine but anything to do with bower throws a segmentation fault - `npm install -g bower` or `bower install`

What can this be due to?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by running

`npm cache clean` and then executing

`npm install -g bower`

Now `bower install` works fine

Leaving this here for others.